# What is the difference between "quick" and "expeditious"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between `quick` and `expeditious`? When the `expeditious` is more appropriate?

Comment: In my experience "expeditious" is a rarer word in spoken English. I encounter it most commonly in the phrase "an expeditious retreat."

Comment: "Expeditious" is an awesome word, and a badly underutilized one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying quick denotes the time in which an action was completed.

Saying expeditious denotes that something was done both quickly and efficiently, indicating quality as well as time.

Interestingly, the frequency of expeditious has dropped significantly since the mid-1800s and has fallen out of use in day-to-day English.